# Quick Action dialog in android having table or list layout

Tags: android, dialog, quickaction

I want to show such popup in android. Quick Action Dialog is the way to implement this but how to show list or table view as in image in quick action dialog. or any other way to implement same UI.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MHQlf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using an Activity with transparent theme adding

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

to the Manifest file and to dismiss it after clicking outside the activity. I used the following code in that activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make us non-modal, so that others can receive touch events.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // ...but notify us that it happened.
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

    // Note that flag changes must happen *before* the content view is set.
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_table);
}    

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.finish ();
}
```